# Pass field name/type as a parameter to a method in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, java-8

I have a List of LocalizedAttributes

```
public class LocalizedAttribute<T> {
    T value;
    Locale locale;
}
```

I have a class which stores the list of the localized attributes;

```
public class A {
    .
    .
    private List<LocalizedAttribute> localizedAttributes;
}
```

I have a class which has some book related info.

```
public class B {
    private String title;
    private String summary;
    private List<String> authors;
    private List<Map<String, String>> publisherRoles;
}
```

I create a bunch of books

```
B bookRelatedInfo1 = new B(); ///fill in values;
B bookRelatedInfo2 = new B(); ///fill in values;
B bookRelatedInfo3 = new B(); ///fill in values;
```

I add this in an object of class A

```
A.setLocalizedAttributes(ImmutableList.of(
            new LocalizedAttribute(bookRelatedInfo1, new Locale("US")),
            new LocalizedAttribute(bookRelatedInfo2, new Locale("DE")),
            new LocalizedAttribute(bookRelatedInfo3, new Locale("JP"))
))
```

Now I want to extract list of localized titles, summary separately.

```
getLocalizedTitles(List<LocalizedAttribute> localizedAttributes) {
    return localizedAttributes.stream()
        .map(localizedAttribute -> {
            Locale locale = localizedAttribute.getLocale();
            B b = (B) localizedAttribute.getValue();
            return new LocalizedAttribute(b.getTitle(), locale);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now If I want to get list of summary I need to write the exact same method again except for `b.getTitle` and so on. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @Eran You're right. Missed it. Updated it in question

Comment: y can you pass another argument to this method and based on that decide whether you want title or summary

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes I can have a bunch of if statements. But where will the strings live? (which class).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a `Function<B,T>` to that method:

```
<T> List<LocalizedAttribute<T>> getLocalizedAttributes(List<LocalizedAttribute<B>> localizedAttributes, Function<B,T> mapper) {
    return localizedAttributes.stream()
        .map(localizedAttribute -> {
            Locale locale = localizedAttribute.getLocale();
            B b = localizedAttribute.getValue();
            return new LocalizedAttribute<T>(mapper.apply(b), locale);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

which can be reduced to:

```
<T> List<LocalizedAttribute<T>> getLocalizedAttributes(List<LocalizedAttribute<B>> localizedAttributes, Function<B,T> mapper) {
    return localizedAttributes.stream()
        .map(la -> new LocalizedAttribute<T>(mapper.apply(la.getValue()), la.getLocale()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
List<LocalizedAttribute<String>> titleList = getLocalizedAttributes(list,B::getTitle);
```

or

```
List<LocalizedAttribute<String>> summaryList = getLocalizedAttributes(list,B::getSummary);
```

Comment: @user1692342 try now.

Comment: The function doesnt have an error. But B::getTitle throws an error saying cannot convert String to T.

Comment: @user1692342 I had a wrong return type for `getLocalizedTitles`. Changed it now.

Comment: Ya I had edited the return type. That isn't the issue. The problem is with the parameter being passed, not return type.

Comment: @user1692342 I was assuming you have a `String getSummary()` method in `class B`. Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: Thats right. getSummary returns a String. Authors returns a List and publishers a List of Map

Comment: Also la.getValue() has to be typecasted.

Comment: @user1692342 If you pass to the method a `List<LocalizedAttribute<B>>` (and not raw `List<LocalizedAttribute>`), you don't have to cast `getValue()` to `B`. (Assuming `getValue()`'s return type is `T` and not `Object`).

Comment: Right. I wasnt passing B in the method. I'm still having the error of cannot convert String to T

Comment: @user1692342 In which class did you put the `getLocalizedAttributes` method?

Comment: part of Class A

Comment: @user1692342 And when you call that method, are you pass to it a `List<LocalizedAttribute>` (as in `private List<LocalizedAttribute> localizedAttributes;` of class `A`) or a `List<LocalizedAttribute<B>>`?

Comment: the method accepts List<LocalizedAttribute<B>>. I pass it List<LocalizedAttribute>.  Not sure if that is the error right now since the error is from B::getTitle

Comment: @user1692342 you must pass it a ` List<LocalizedAttribute<B>>`. It could be the problem. Java 8 error messages are sometimes misleading.

Comment: I modified it. My class A has List<LocalizedAttribute<B>>
My getLocalizedAttributes takes in only Function<TitleInfo, B> as it can access the value of localizedAttributes from the object itself. But still same error

Comment: @user1692342 `Function<TitleInfo, B>`? What is TitleInfo? Shouldn't it be String?

Comment: Sorry Function<B,T>

Comment: @user1692342 I can't test the code myself at the moment. Perhaps I'll be able to do that later.

Comment: ok cool thanks! I'll try in the meantime. So frustrating to be so close but stuck with an error! But this looks like a great solution!

Comment: were you able to find the problem? I wasnt able to. Also what is the difference between List<LocalizedAttribute> , List<LocalizedAttribute<B>> and List<LocalizedAttribute<B, Locale>>

Comment: The problem was I was saving it to List<LocalizedAttribute> rather than List<LocalizedAttribute<String>> . What is the difference between these 2 data structures?

Comment: If you store the value returned by `getLocalizedAttributes()` in a `List<LocalizedAttribute>` instead of a `List<LocalizedAttribute<String>>`, the compiler doesn't know that the passed function should be a `Function<B,String>`. You should never use raw types (such as `LocalizedAttribute`). @user1692342