# Run the same method on different field names

Tags: java

Let's say I have a `Student` class like so:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
}
```

And I have a list of such students:

```
private List<Student> studentList;
```

Requirement: I want to calculate average weight and height of all the students.

Therefore, I want to write a method named `findAverage`, where I can somehow send the `fieldName` as argument and the method will fetch the data accordingly as follows:

```
public double findAverage(List<Student> studentList, String fieldName){
    List<Double> numList = new Arraylist<>();
    for(Student student: studentList){
        numList.add(studentList.getFieldName());    // How do I map the correct field name here?
    }
    double total = 0.0;
    for(Double item: numList){
        total += item;
    }
    return total/(double)numList.size();
}

System.out.println("Average Height :- " + findAverage(studentList, height));
System.out.println("Average Weight :- " + findAverage(studentList, weight));
```

Comment: You need to put a condition within the `for` loop to determine which property to use. I would also merge those two `for` loops together; `numList` doesn't appear to serve any purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass field name/type as a parameter to a method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937264/pass-field-name-type-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-in-java)

Comment: With streams and map/reduce it's hardly worth writing a method at all ... `System.out.println("Avg Height = " + students.stream().map(s -> s.getHeight()).reduce(0.0, Double::sum) / students.size());`

Answer (score 2):

Using java stream API you could use a function to extract the field and calculate the averages like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> students = ...;

    System.out.println(getAverage(students, Student::getHeight));
    System.out.println(getAverage(students, Student::getWeight));
}

private static double getAverage(Collection<Student> students, ToDoubleFunction<Student> toDoubleFunction) {
    return students
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(toDoubleFunction)
            .average()
            .orElse(Double.NaN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the (common) case of writing where the property to access is not only determined at runtime but already at compile time, I would suggest to avoid reflection.

This means, instead of trying to directly extract values of fields by providing their name (`fieldName`), you should provide a function like a [`ToDoubleFunction<Student>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToDoubleFunction.html) or [`Function<Student, Double>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) which extracts the `double` value from a student.

Doing so will make your code more refactoring-friendly and errors will be detected at compile-time instead of runtime.

Your function would then look like this

```java
public double findAverage(List<Student> studentList, ToDoubleFunction<Student> getValue) {
    List<Double> numList = new Arraylist<>();
    for(Student student: studentList){
        numList.add(getValue.applyAsDouble(student));
    }
    return ...;
}
```

and you would apply it like this:

```java
double avgHeight = findAverage(studentList, Student::getHeight);
double avgWeight = findAverage(studentList, Student::getWeight);
```

or (slightly longer):

```java
double avgHeight = findAverage(studentList, student -> student.getHeight());
double avgWeight = findAverage(studentList, student -> student.getWeight());
```

Comment: Apart from the actual problem you wanted to solve, I would recommed to have a look at the Stream API which allows you, to use the concept of "mapping" values of a stream (applying a function and then working only with those results)  and then proceed with forming an average. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877843/10245948

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do this with reflection, ***but*** it's fragile. You could collapse the number of possible `Exception`(s) in the `throws` but I wanted to give **fragile** extra **emphasis**. You are assuming that `private` fields are accessible from the caller; sometimes they are. But sometimes they are not. And it depends on packaging and Java version. Regardless,

```
public double findAverage(List<Student> studentList, String fieldName) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, 
               IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Field f = Student.class.getField(fieldName);
    int count = 0;
    double acc = 0;
    for (Student student : studentList) {
        acc += f.getDouble(student);
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        return acc / count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Method reference to dynamically define the way to get the value of the field:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private double height;
    private double weight;

    // note I define getters here, probably you'll have those anyway
    public double getHeight() {return height;}
    public double getWeight() {return weight;}
}
```

Now define the method of average calculation:

```
import java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction;
...
public double findAverage(List<Student> studentList, ToDoubleFunction<Student> func){
    List<Double> numList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Student student: studentList){
        // note this call!
        numList.add(func.applyAsDouble(student));  
    }
    // whatever you need for calculating the average, omitted
}
```

Now if you want to calculate the avg. of height you should:

```
List<Student> students = ...
findAverage(students, Student::getHeight);
```

for weight average you make the following call:

```
List<Student> students = ...
findAverage(students, Student::getWeight);
```

Now, although you haven't asked, but you can use streams to calculate the average as well. I've posted the original version because its easier to understand the usage of `ToDoubleFunction` that way, but probably you would like to end up with the (arguably cleaner) implementation:

```
public double findAverage(List<Student> studentList, ToDoubleFunction<Student> func){
        return studentList.stream()
                .mapToDouble(func)
                .average()
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a condition inside for loop to determine which property to use, then remove the second for loop because it is unnecessary.

```
 double total = 0;
 for(Student student: studentList){
        if(fieldName.equals("height")) {
            numList.add(studentList.getHeight());
            total += studentList.getHeight();
        } else {
            numList.add(studentList.getWeight());
            total += studentList.getWeight();
        }
    }
```